# Nest JS - Return undefined when trying to get user context in RolesGuard

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport

I am trying to add role guard in Nest JS API. I used Passport, Jwt authentication for this.
In my RolesGuard class I made the request and get the user from it to check the user role valid or not. I attached the code below.

**roles.guard.ts**

```js
    canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {

      const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());

      if (!roles) {
        return true;
      }

      const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      const user: User = request.user;

      return this.userService.findOne(user.id).pipe(
        map((user: User) => {
          const hasRole = () => roles.indexOf(user.role) > -1;
          let hasPermission: boolean = false;

          if (hasRole()) {
            hasPermission = true;
          }
          return user && hasPermission;
        }),
      );
  }
```

Problem here is context.switchToHttp().getRequest() returns object, which is undefined. So I could not get user details from it.
After I had some research about this error I found that order of the decorators in controller can be the issue. Then I changed the order, but still problem appears as same. Bellow I added that code also.

**user.controller.ts**

```js
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard)
    @hasRoles(UserRole.USER)
    @Get()
    findAll(): Observable<User[]> {
      return this.userService.findAll();
    }
```

-Thank you-

Comment: Do you have `APP_GUARD` with `useClass: RolesGuard` in one of your modules?

Comment: I resolved the issue by myself. Thank you for the consideration @Jay McDoniel

Comment: What was the issue? I'm also having trouble with an undefined request.

Comment: @user14659427 It would be great if you mention the solution too. It helps others facing the same issue.

Comment: i find the answer in here https://discord.com/channels/520622812742811698/1081157683538825257/1081161337054433280. You can try it

Answer (score 1):

if you are using graphql you can make the changes to fit the code below

```js
    import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
    import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
    import { Role } from 'src/enums/role.enum';
    import { ROLES_KEY } from '../auth';
    @Injectable()
    export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
        constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}
    
        canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
            const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, [
                context.getHandler(),
                context.getClass(),
            ]);
            if (!requiredRoles) {
                return true;
            }
            const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
            const user = ctx.getContext().req.user;
            return requiredRoles.some((role) => user.roles?.includes(role));
        }
    }
```

if you are not using graphql, make the changes to fit the code below

```js
    import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}
    
      canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
        const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, [
          context.getHandler(),
          context.getClass(),
        ]);
        if (!requiredRoles) {
          return true;
        }
        const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        return requiredRoles.some((role) => user.roles?.includes(role));
      }
    }
```

then in you controller you can do

```js
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard)
    @hasRoles(UserRole.USER)
    @Get()
    findAll(): Observable<User[]> {
      return this.userService.findAll();
    }
```

finally, for all this to work add the global guard to your `app.module.ts`
like so

```js
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { AppController } from './app.controller';
    import {MongooseModule} from '@nestjs/mongoose';
    import { AppService } from './app.service';
    import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
    import configuration from 'src/config/configuration';
    import { RolesGuard } from 'src/auth/auth';
    import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
    import { AdminsModule } from 'src/admin/admins.module';
    import { config } from 'dotenv';
    import * as Joi from 'joi';
    
    config();
    
    @Module({
      imports: [
        // other modules
        UsersModule,
    
        // configuration module
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
          cache: true,
          load: [configuration],
          expandVariables: true,
          // validate stuff with Joi
          validationSchema: Joi.object({
            NODE_ENV: Joi.string()
              .valid('development', 'production', 'test', 'provision')
              .default('development'),
            PORT: Joi.number().default(5000),
          }),
          validationOptions: {
            // allow unknown keys (change to false to fail on unknown keys)
            allowUnknown: true,
            abortEarly: true,
          },
        }),
        // connect to mongodb database
        MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.DB_URL, {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
        }),
      ],
    
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [
        AppService,
        {
          provide: 'APP_GUARD',
          useClass: RolesGuard,
        }
      ],
    })
    
    export class AppModule {}
```